# $geoNear before $lookup is a performance problem?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two assets. one big and one small.
I related the small one to the big one.
I have the geolocation data on the big one.
I want to use the aggregate pipeline for $match geolocation data. but aggregate needs $geoNear at the first stage.
I wanted to know if is it a problem for performance to apply a query on a big one.
and if so how can I apply the query on a small one alongside bypassing $geoNear at the first step requirement?

I searched all the internet to find a solution I didn't find a solution.